# Selected cell in dataGridView1

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hey guys so I'm trying to receive the column/row of the last edited cell
however when I use the following code, what I receive is the cell that I select next(by clicking), since it is the one that is being selected.

Any way around this? Maybe I just don't have the right properties for the dataGridView

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
         int column = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex;
         int row = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridViewCellEventArgs` provides data for DataGridView events related to cell and row operations. It exposes two properties `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex`

```
int column = e.ColumnIndex;
int row = e.RowIndex;
```

**More:** As @Mr_Green pointed, *`e.ColumnIndex`* and *`e.RowIndex`* will be *`-1`* for *`ColumnHeader & RowHeader`*.

Comment: Thanks Kaf and @user574632, do you guys mind explaining why the argument e worked instead of dataGridView1?

Comment: Read this [MSDN Documentation] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.aspx) for details.

Comment: @KelseyAbreu If you don't mind I'd like to note that these indexes starts from 0. So if you click and edit your top left cell you'll get column=0 and row=0;

Comment: @Sylca AFAIK, these indexes starts from `-1` including RowHeader and ColumnHeader. So, to avoid errors, it is preferred to set `if(e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)` while coding.

Comment: @Mr_Green thank you for your kind elaboration. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int column = e.ColumnIndex;
        int row = e.RowIndex;
    }
```